# LINQ select column(s) of table before doing multiple joins

Tags: linq

After running the query below and hovering over "usersToWork" when debugging, I can view all of the properties of the single entry that I get returned to me in addition to the other tables that have relations to this value.  What I need to display to the user is the "Lines.Id" (Lines being the table and Id being the column in the Lines table) value, however that value gets lost from the SelectMany() statements.  Is there anyway to select that "Lines.Id" value to include in the final value that I get from all of my joins?  In the code below, I commented out what I want but I can't place that there otherwise I get error on the first SelectMany statement saying 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Shifts' and no extension method 'Shifts' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found.'

Correct me if I'm wrong but SelectMany() selects all of the columns from what you want to join on.  In this case, in the first SelectMany() I get only values from the "Shifts" table and in the second SelectMany() I get only values from the "Users" table.  Why is this different from the SQL join?  When joining in SQL you can get every column as you join them together, SelectMany() yields only the values of the second table that you are joining on.  Is it even possible to get that value in the "Lines" table or will I have to do another query?  Any help would be great.

```
int idEnteredByUser = 123;
var usersToWork = entityDataModel.Lines
                //....NOT IN MY CODE NOW....
                // .Select(line => line.Id)//THIS IS WHAT I NEED.
                // .Select(line => line.Description, line.Id//OR THIS TO RETURN TWO VALUES IF POSSIBLE

                //This is my current code, I need to include on of the select lines above.
                .SelectMany(line => line.Shifts) //Join lines on shifts.
                .Where(shift => shift.EndTime >= DateTime.Now) //Join restricted times.
                .SelectMany(user => user.Users) //Join the restricted shift times on users.
                .Where(user => user.UserId == idEnteredByUser ); //Only look for the specific user
```

Comment: What is the relationship of `user` to `shift` or `line`?

Comment: "Line" and "Shift" are related by the "LineId" column that is in both columns.  "Shift" and "Users" are related by the "ShiftId" column that are in both columns.  The SelectMany() takes care of the relational join though, that's why they aren't specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works much easier using LINQ query syntax.

I'm assuming that you made a typo in your posted code and that `user` is a property of `shift`.

```
var idEnteredByUser = 123;
var usersToWork = 
    from line in entityDataModel.Lines
    from shift in line.Shifts
    where shift.EndTime >= DateTime.Now
    from user in shift.Users
    where user.UserId == idEnteredByUser
    select new
    {
        Description = line.Description,
        Id = line.Id
    };
```

Comment: So is it not possible to do that in the lambda notation then?  What you supplied for the LINQ query syntax makes sense, but I was wondering if it's possible to tack on that additional property while doing the lambda syntax

Comment: It would be far more difficult and certainly not so concise.